# Adobe Photoshop CS6 crashes with two videocards

Tags: graphics-card, adobe-photoshop, crash

After installing 2nd videocard Adobe Photoshop CS6 crashes with some actions. Only Photoshop crashes, not system.

So question is: how to solve this without removing 2nd videocard? I have 4 monitors and no opportunity to buy videocard that supports 4 monitors.

OS: Win 7 x64

Cards: ATI 3650 on x16 and ATI X1650 on x1

Comment: Which OS are you using? What is the make and model of the video cards? Have you tried re-installing the drivers for the graphics cards? When you say crash, do you mean only the program or the entire computer? Does your computer display an error message when it "crashes"? Have you looked in the event viewer under application to see if Windows has an error relating to the crash, if you are using a Windows operating system of coarse. Also, which actions are you referring to?

Comment: OK, I will put in question

Comment: Just FYI, I did update my original comment with more questions.

Comment: Yes, Windows says "Photoshop work stopped by error" (translation from russian)

Comment: No, system is Russian. Photoshop is English.

Comment: Hmm... a little vague... I would try re-installing the graphics card drivers. Also, which actions cause the program to crash? Sorry, I realized you meant that the system is Russian... Sorry for that last weird comment...

Comment: Re-installing the graphics card drivers doesn't help

Comment: Many, changing tool for example

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9288/discussion-between-david-and-rustam)